# Page jumps to top jquery .animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrollto

My problem is when I click on a (fixed position) div to animate another div the entire page jumps to the top. I have tried preventDefault and return false, but nothing seems to fix the problem! Please help.

Here is the script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("#info").animate({ 
            width: "0",
            height:"0"
        }, 100 );

        $("#info").hide(),
        $(".container").animate({ 
            left:"0",
            width:"100%"
        }, 100 );
        return false;
    });

    $(".sidebar").click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        $("#info").show(),
        $("#info").animate({ 
            width: "25%",
            height:"100%",
            left:"0"
        }, 100 );

        $(".container").animate({ 
            left: "25%",
            width:"75%"
            }, 100 );
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Try changing the interval to 1500 instead of 100

Comment: is there any particular reason you use commas after the hide() and show() instead of semi-colons?

Comment: Susanth - that just makes the animation of the div slower, page still jumps to top

Comment: mason81 I have changed commas to semi-colons. As you can see, Im a learner :)

Comment: Try `event.stopPropagation();` [link](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: @Bondye Doesn't matter - the `return false;` takes care of both `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`...so in this case, the `evt.preventDefault()` is redundant if using `return false;` at the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the trigger element is an empty anchor

```
<a href="#">some val</a>
```

then the location hash changes to "#" after clicking it. By not finding an area that corresponds with an empty hash, the browser scrolls the page to the top.
Here's what you can do:

```
$('a[href=#]').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Or you could do it like they did 10 years ago:  change the empty anchor href to an empty javascript statement:

```
<a href="javascript:void();">some val</a>
```

**update**
After looking at the markup, I've got the solution. All you have to do is to make sure that your `.container` has the ability to scroll. While animating, the elements gets the css property `overflow : hidden` (i don't really know where it gets it from) and that kind of *resets* your scroll position. So, all you have to do is to add this to your stylesheet:

```
.container{
    overflow: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, the trigger is simply  <div class="sidebar"><h2>October 2012</h2></div> With the click event defined for this div on document ready.

Comment: Well, sry, but without any other html/css markup I can't really get the idea of what's going on. Consider making a live demo via http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: gion, you are a legend. I was so stuck on this, thinking it must be my lack of javacript knowledge setting me back! But really it was in the CSS - I never would have picked that up! THANKS!!!